# Why expo ImagePicker is not giving me an option to trim the video before/when uploading from an android device, even after using videoMaxDuration: 30,

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-image-picker, expo-av

in IOS, we can't upload any video that is greater than 30 Seconds.
and if you try to upload it would give you an option to trim it to 30 seconds like Whatsapp, but on android it is taking any video that we are uploading.

Any idea what might be causing this behaviour and how to resolve this.
Thanks in Advance.

```
const _pickDocument = async () => {
let permissions = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();

if (permissions.granted === false) {
  alert("Permission is required. Please enable it from settings.");
  return;
}
let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
  mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
  allowsEditing: true,
  quality: 1,
  videoMaxDuration: 30,
  
  
});

if (result.cancelled === true) return;
setSelectedImage((prev) => [...prev, result]);
};
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this one?

Comment: No man I gave up on it after doing some trail and error but I have recently came across the SDK called img.ly that allows you to trim the video and that is pretty simple but it is paid only for production usage.